# how to use logging component flexibility

Tags: c#, logging, plugin-architecture

My team is developing a Plugin project, in which Host application coordinates Plugins work (each Plugin has a specific function and will be executed on a seperate Thread). I'm writing Host application and define IPlugin interface; other developer will refer to my IPlugin interface and develop his Plugins.
And have a problem raise on my team: some developers use Nlog to logging their Plugin work, but other developers use Log4Net.
My question is: how to let each plugin can use logging component that it like to use?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So say you make an interface:

```
interface ILoggerPlugin
{
    void Log(LogInfo info);
}
```

and a class for all your information

```
class LogInfo
{
    public string Application;
    public Exception LoggedException;
}
```

Now, if you handover the interface and ask all the dev's to follow this then all the other bits will be abstracted. The plugin end-user won't have to know what is being used as the implementation. Weather its NLog or Log4Net.

We have implemented something very much like that. To top it off, we also have a target variable which points to database, a file and/or Email for critical ones.

Comment: I really don't understand you. Do you mean I need create an interface (like above) and then other Plugin developer will implement it and in my host application needn't care about logging engine (Nlog or lognet).

Comment: You are very much right. If you create an interface and ask your dev to implement it, they will have to adhere to the signature of the methods. They can later use either nLog or log4net to implement the methods. Now, when the end user uses the plugin they will see the methods from your interface.

Comment: have two problems in your approach: (1). if i do as you said, in my host application, i must reference to both Nlog.dll and log4net.dll and then if another developer use another logging engine (for example: Xlog), i also must reference to Xlog.dll; (2). if i do as the problem (1), the plugins can't control its logging work, all of logging work will be set in my host application. if you have free time, you can create a solution (like my solution above), you will see these two problems.

Comment: could you create a sample of what you have done and put it on git. I will have a look and help you out

Comment: thanks so much for your support, could you give your email adress and then i can send my document to you. In fact, my project is very very simple, i only need send a word document to you is enough.